# How do I plot a hist3 in matlab with a third variable for the height?

Tags: matlab, knn

I have a table with 3 variables - `number_k`, `Distance_used` and `accuracy`, and I want to plot how the 2 variables influence the `accuracy`.

Comment: You want a `bar3` plot?

Comment: Any plot would be okay as long as it shows the changes on accuracy based on the two other variables.

Comment: Have you tried `bar3`? Why does it not do what you want